# how to iterate or loop 10^15 within less time in java

Tags: java

$ i need to iterate or loop for around 10^15 time how to reduce the time of execution 
i have tried to reduce the time for int max value but i could not reduce the time of execution

```
int k=0;
for(int l = 1;l<1000000000;l++){
    for(int i=0;i<40;i++){
        if(a[i]==1){
           for(long j=x;j<=k;j++){
              if(j%(i+1)==0){
                System.out.println(k);
            }
        }
    }x++;
}
size += s.size();
k+=40;
if(size>n)break;
s.clear();
}
```

here i could not loop it

Comment: What are you trying to do? Most likely printing to the screen is what is taking the most time in the code example posted above.

Comment: You are missing an end curly brace `}` right after the `println` statement. And I wonder if that's the root cause of your performance - the inner most for loop continues to run the rest of the program inadvertently. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a micro-optimization, but you can combine the outermost for-loop with the one directly below it. Notice the change from int to long.

```
for(int l = 1;l<1000000000;l++){
    for(int i=0;i<40;i++){
        if(a[i]==1){
           for(long j=x;j<=k;j++){
              if(j%(i+1)==0){
```

Becomes this:

```
for(long l = 1;l<40000000000L;l++){
    if(a[l%40]==1){
       for(long j=x;j<=k;j++){
          if(j%(l%40+1)==0){
```

I haven't measured this or simulated a perf run.  So YMMV.